# Changing the shape of a cell

Tags: mxgraph

I am new to mxgraph and attempting to work through the basic examples within the javascript folder. How do I change the shape using graph.insertVertex function? The user manual states that the style can be changed using the following:

```
graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello',  20, 20, 80, 30, 'ROUNDED;strokeColor=red;fillColor=green');
```

The strokeColor and fillColor attributes work as expected but 'ROUNDED' has no effect. I have also tried other shapes, none of which seem to work - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs are probably out of date, I'll fix.

The style is rounded=1. In terms of styles two good ways to get info on them:

1. This [post](https://support.draw.io/display/DOB/2016/04/28/draw.io+Cell+Styles) links to a bunch style examples designed to show the main style groups
2. Go to [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/?splash=0) (built using mxGraph) and use the "edit style" button in the right-hand format panel when a single shape is selected. For example, drag on a rounded rectangle from the general library, click edit style and you'll see the mxGraph styles on that shape (including rounded=1).